# Why there is so few of Beryllium alloys?

Tags: material-science

Beryllium,a metal with very unique set of characteristics yet there is relatively very few beryllium alloys.There is AlBeMet and beryllium copper alloys,but the beryllium content is very low in those beryllium coppers.

Why isnt there more alloys that have high beryllium content? I know it cost alot,is toxic in powder form but I doubt that is only reason why is there so few alloys.

Is it becose Be doesnt mix well with other elements for some reason? Nearly all other metal elements I know have some complex alloy with many elements in it that doubles or triples yield strenght and hardness.For example,no one is building planes from pure aluminum,they use the much stronger 7075 alloy,no one is building stuff from pure iron,they use strong maraging steels etc.

All these other metals have alloys that make them significantly different to pure metals.Especialy the strenght and hardness gets much higher,there is no alloy like that for beryllium.Albemet is neighter stronger or harder than pure Be,beryllium copper have like 1.5% Be,its almost pure copper "sprinkled" by little bit of Be.

Comment: Since friction, wear, machining, polishing, ... all create fine beryllium oxide dust that is toxic to those that breath it, your dismissal of toxicity as a prime reason _not_ to use it seems a bit off. Even Beryllium copper is being phased out in many places for this reason.

Comment: Interesting,I didnt know that.Maybe they could machine  it in vacuum,argon or nitrogen atmosphere,or even electrical discharge machining could help.Also,I didnt dismiss the toxicity as being strong factor,merely hypothesized.It very well might be prime reason,I dont know,I certainly dont dismiss it.

Comment: In real world usage you will have processes that continue to create beryllia dust. Even those beryllium-copper probe tips generate measurable contamination. Beryllium oxide is nasty, nasty stuff.

Comment: Even when I have some item sitting in living room that have beryllium copper screws exposed to air?

Comment: No, but the person screwing in all those screws on the assembly line will be exposed, so you might not die of asphyxiation, but they can. And anybody who rubs on it a lot. For example, beryllium copper was commonly used for probe tips in electrical test, repeatedly making contact with printed circuit boards. That mechanical action results in friction/wear and the release of copper and beryllia. Copper isn't a major health problem, the beryllia is. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berylliosis. Note that a single exposure to beryllia may be sufficient.

Comment: I know about Berylliosis,its the probe tip thing I hear (read) for first time.I will definately research it since I also study EE and will handle lot of oscilloscope probes as result.

Comment: *I know it cost a lot* The reason for using alloys in the first place is to combine small amounts of expensive metals with larger amounts of relatively inexpensive ones.  If you don't actually *need* to make materials with high proportions of expensive metals in them (because they might have properties impractical to make any other way), you just don't.  In real world engineering cost is a major consideration.

Comment: @StephenG: Cost is one reason for using alloys rather than pure metals, but it isn't the only one. Steel is an alloy of iron and carbon, and the carbon isn't added because iron is too expensive.